# Function with limiting behavior between polynomial and exponential?

Tags: limits

Does there exist a function $f$ such that

For all $p>0$, $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac {|f(n)|}{|n^p|}>1$$
And

For all $a>0$, $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac {|f(n)|}{|e^{an}|}<1$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ e^{\sqrt n} $$

.......................